# How set visibility to constrainlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have constraint layout xml , it has 2 constraint layouts inside. I kept First layout visibility to gone in xml. And tried to set visibility to that first layout programmatically in activity.
But visility is not working. I'm new to constraint layout. Please help me out to set visibility to constraint layout

Comment: You do not need to have nested layouts in ConstraintLayout, that is the whole point. Try pasting your XML in question.

Comment: Please share the minimum version of your XML layout

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure you have set an id to that ConstraintLayout in your xml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After this, go to the Activity Java file (MainActivity.java or which activity you have to show that layout) and Create a ConstraintLayout field, then assign that specific view into that field.

```
package com.legendsayantan.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ConstraintLayout firstlayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstlayout=findViewById(R.id.firstlayout);
    }
    public static void showView(View view){
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public static void hideView(View view){
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Now, to change visibility of any ConstraintLayout, Simply call these `showView()`
And `hideView()` methods and pass the corresponding ConstraintLayout to that method.

For Example:

This will hide the firstlayout:

```
hideView(firstlayout);
```

This will show the firstlayout:

```
showView(firstlayout);
```

Let me know if your problem is solved now...